# How to have 3 tables in one view asp.net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 3 tables

```
Customer
Assign
Employee
```

I have linked `Assign` and `Employee` together as there is a need for an FK in assign, however, no relation is needed for the customer however I wish to display customer in view index of `Assign`. `Assign` displays the data and ViewModel is used for showing `Employee` name

However, how do I show the customer table in this view where the hardcoded Name and Id is

Assign model

```
public class Assign
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeNameId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeNameId")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Customer model

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Employee model

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }
}
```

Assign ViewModel

```
public class AsignVM
{
    public Asign Asign { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Assign controller

```
public class AsignController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public AsignController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Asign> objList = _db.Asigns;
        IEnumerable<Customer> assdasd = _db.Customers;

        foreach (var obj in objList)
        {
            obj.Employee = _db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.EmployeeNameId);
        }

        return View(objList);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //IEnumerable<SelectListItem> typeDropDown = _db.Employees.Select(i => new SelectListItem
        //{
        //    Text =i.Name + "  Speciality =  " + i.Speciality,
        //    Value = i.Id.ToString()
        //});

        //ViewBag.typeDropDown = typeDropDown;

        AsignVM asignVM = new AsignVM()
        {
            Asign = new Asign(),
            TypeDropDown = _db.Employees.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            })
        };

        return View(asignVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(AsignVM obj)
    {
        _db.Asigns.Add(obj.Asign);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var obj = _db.Asigns.Find(id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
    {
        var obj = _db.Asigns.Find(id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _db.Asigns.Remove(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Assign index

```
@model IEnumerable<HandyApp.Models.Asign>

<h1 style="margin-left: 52px;margin-top: 21px;">Customer Jobs</h1>
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 12px;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;width: 143px;">Customer name</th>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;">Job ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>1223</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 4px;">view details</button><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 4px;">Delete</button><a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 4px;" asp-controller="Asign" asp-action="Create">assign</a></td>
            </tr>
       
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-left: 52px;margin-top: 21px;">Assigned jobs</h1>
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 12px;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;width: 143px;">Customer name</th>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;">Tasks</th>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;">Status</th>
                <th style="margin-top: 0px;">Assigned to</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Tasks</td>
                <td>@item.Status</td>
                <td>@item.Employee.Name</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left: 7px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 4px;" asp-controller="Asign" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.Id">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have linked Assign and Employee together as there is a need for an
> FK in assign, however, no relation is needed for the customer however
> I wish to display customer in view index of Assign. Assign displays
> the data and ViewModel is used for showing Employee name
>
> However, how do I show the customer table in this view where the
> hardcoded Name and Id is

Since the Customer doesn't contain the relationship with Assign, Employee and the AsignVM Model, to display Customer data in the Assign Index View, you have to use **ViewData** or **ViewBag**.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Asign> objList = _db.Asigns;
        IEnumerable<Customer> assdasd = _db.Customers;
        foreach (var obj in objList)
        {
            obj.Employee = _db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == obj.EmployeeNameId);
        }
        // use ViewBag pass the data to the View
        ViewBag.Customer = assdasd;

        return View(objList);
    }
```

Then, in the Index View page, check if ViewBag is null or not, if the ViewBag contains data, convert it to `IEnumerable<Customer>`, then, display the data.

```
    @if (ViewBag.Customer != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Customer>)ViewBag.Customer)
        {
             //display the records.
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td> 
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

More detail infromation, see [Passing data to views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#passing-data-to-views).